# Catching a json response from a webview

Tags: android

**What i am trying to do:**

- I am loading a url into webview
- I am traversing 2 3 pages inside webview
- In the final page a transaction is done and a json response is
  returned
- I need to catch that response

### How to achieve this IN ANDROID?

currently i have successfully loaded the url

Myclass.java

```
public class Myclass extends ActionBarActivity{

    public static Context context = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_buycredits);

        context = this;


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.windhya_actionbar_color)));
        // ////////////////-------SUPORT---MENU----IRRESPECTIVE--OF---VERSIONS---////////////////////////////
        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                    .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Ignore
        }

        // ////////////////-------SUPORT---MENU----IRRESPECTIVE--OF---VERSIONS---////////////////////////////


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
        case android.R.id.home:
           finish();

            // Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        MyWebViewFragment fragment = (MyWebViewFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myweb_fragment);
        WebView webView = fragment.myWebView;

        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    static public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

        WebView myWebView;
        //final static String myBlogAddr = "https://www.payumoney.com/";

        //final static String myBlogAddr = "https://entech1.cloudapp.net:8001/paymentGateWay/";


        final static String myBlogAddr = Keys.pamentGateway_api;

        String myUrl;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_webfragment, container, false);

            myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

            if(myUrl == null){
                myUrl = myBlogAddr;
            }

            Map <String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
            extraHeaders.put("phonenumber",AppController.getPhoneNumber()); 
            extraHeaders.put("authtoken",AppController.getAuthCode()); 

            this.myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
            this.myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
            this.myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            this.myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            this.myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);



            this.myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url,
                        String message, JsResult result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(context, message, 5000).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(context, super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result)+"", 5000).show();
                    return false;
                    //return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                }
            });
            myWebView.loadUrl(myUrl,extraHeaders);



            return view;

        }

        private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                myUrl = url;
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

    }
}
```

***hOW TO ACHIEVE THIS***

Comment: call the class for catching your json. but it need to code your html as well. for adding the class, you can use `yourwebview.addjavascriptinterface(yourclass,yourclassid)`

Comment: @Devrath Have you found any perfect solution to do same?

Comment: @Devrath, were you able to find the same ?

Answer (score 0):

> Catching a json response from a webview

Not possible to capture html text from WeView.

But you can try it in this way:

**1.** Set `setWebViewClient` to get current url from webview :

```
this.myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if [url is last page which contain json string]
          THEN
             use HttpClient to get string from url
           END
          ELSE
           view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
});
```

**2.**  In `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` check if `url` is last page then use HTTP GET request(HttpGet) using `HttpClient` to get response String .

Answer (score -1):

First override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` and `onPageFinished` of WebViewClient

```
 @override
 public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    isContent= (url.contains("filename/urlpattern"));
 }

 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

   if(isContent) { 

        URL aUrl = new URL(url); 
        URLConnection conn = aUrl.openConnection(); 
        conn.connect(); 
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
        // Use inputstream code to read the json..

        return true;
}

return false;
}
```